# How to type a jQuery .on("paste", hdl)

Tags: jquery, typescript, clipboarddata

I'm trying to define the handler for a `contenteditable <div>` under Chrome (only). I have a jQuery `JQuery<HTMLElement>` for it and I want to add a `paste` event handler with `.on()`, but typescript complains at this point with:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
'TypeEventHandlers<HTMLElement, (event: ClipboardEvent) => void, HTMLElement, HTMLElement>'.ts(2769)
JQuery.d.ts(8059, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

The code is:

```
const pasteHandler = (event: ClipboardEvent): void => {
    const pastedData = event.clipboardData!.getData("text/plain");
    console.log(pastedData);
};
$("div").on("paste", pasteHandler); // <- error message from here
```

What is the correct typing for `pasteHandler`? I tried, but was not able to decipher the jQuery type files.
The only workaround I have found is to substitute the `on` call with:
`$("div")[0].addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler);`
Thanks for your help!
Please do not focus on the jQuery use. It is an old code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be

```
const pasteHandler = (event: JQuery.TriggeredEvent<HTMLElement, undefined, HTMLElement, HTMLElement): void => {
  const pastedData = (event.originalEvent as ClipboardEvent).clipboardData?.getData("text/plain");
  //...
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-noether-lgnsi?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Fantastic Mosh! adding a type definition for event (just for readability) and managing null clipboard data solved my problem. Thanks!